# When a prime ideal is restricted to a basic open subset of projective space, is it still prime?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $I\subset k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ is a prime ideal.
Now restricted on the basic open subset $\mathbb{P}^n_{x_i}$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$, is $I$ still prime?

Note:
1. Here $\mathbb{P}^n_{x_i}$ is defined by $x_i\neq 0$.
2. By restriction, I mean when an element in $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ is regarded as a function on $\mathbb{P}^n_{x_i}$, is the ideal still prime? Well, thanks to @Georges, we realize that a general function in $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ cannot be regarded as a function on $\mathbb{P}^n_{x_i}$.

What I really want to know is: when restricted to $\mathbb{P}^n_{x_i}$, is a homogeneous prime ideal $I$ still prime?

Many thanks.

Comment: By the restriction, do you mean the image in the localized ring corresponding to that open set?

Comment: @Tobias Yep, I wonder when an element in $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ is regarded as a function on $\mathbb{P}^n_{x_i}$, is $I$ still prime?

Comment: This is not correct: an element of $k[x_0, x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ cannot be seen as a function on $\mathbb{P}^n_{x_i}$  and an element of $k[ x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ even less so.

Comment: @georges Maybe you are right because a function on $\mathbb{P}^n$ should be homogeneous. Indeed, I am working on such a problem: when restricted on $\mathbb{P}^n_{x_i}$, is a homogeneous prime ideal $I\in k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ still prime? Any suggestions?

Comment: Roughly speaking, yes, but all this should be presented in a more rigorous way. I might come back here but meanwhile you should reinstall  the variable $x_0$ in your last sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is more algebraic than geometric. For instance, (regular) functions on $\mathbb{P^n}$ are measured by $H^0 (\mathbb{P^n}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^n}})$, and this is $k$.

Let $p$ be a homogeneous prime ideal in $S$ which is not $(x_0,\dots, x_n)$. Then there is a point $x \in \mathbb{P^n}$ which corresponds to $p$. Since the basic open subsets cover $\mathbb{P^n}$, there exists at least on basic open subset which contains $x$. Now, this open subsets is Affine and is Spec of $S' = k[x_0/x_i, \dots, x_n/x_i]$.

Observe that $i: S \subseteq S[1/x_i]$ and $j: S' = [S[1/x_i]]_0 \subseteq S[1/x_i]$. The extension of $p$ to $S[1/x_i]$ is prime by our choice of $x_i$, and a preimage of a prime ideal is a prime. Hence $j^{-1}(i(P))$ is the prime.

Comment: @yougsu But I want to show $I$ is prime when restricted to every basic open subset of $P$. Is it possible? If not, what other conditions are needed?

Comment: I don't think that is correct. For instance, take $S = k[x,y]$ and $p = (x)$. Then on $\mathbb{P}^1_x$ it is not a prime. Look at $\cap D(x_i)$. I'm not sure if $D(x_i)$ or $X_{x_i}$ is the correct notation for distinguished open subsets.

Comment: Well, generally speaking, this is not correct. If you are interested, I am working on such a problem: as we know, the image of 2-fold Veronese embedding from $\mathbb{P}^n$ to $\mathbb{P}^N$ is determined by some homogeneous ideal $I$, and I want to show $I$ is radical when restricted to every basic open subset of $\mathbb{P}^N$. I thought that if I could prove that claim, then my original assertion is proved as well. Now, it seems a bit difficult to go this way. Could you give me some insight?

Comment: Well, $I$ being radical is not an issue since $I$ is a prime ideal. The question is whether $I$ remains as a proper ideal or not.

Comment: But we haven't yet proved $I$ remains prime in $\mathbb{P}^N_{x_i}$.

Comment: I thought you wanted to show is that such $I$ remains as a radical ideal, and it follows since $I$ is prime.

Comment: Why does "I is a prime ideal" imply that "restricted on a basic open subset, I is radical"? This is my question.

Comment: It remains as a prime ideal if $p$ does not meet $x_i$, or it becomes a unit ideal if it meets $x_i$. Either case it is a radical ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The statement you want to make is the following. Let $S = k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$. There are bijections
\begin{align*}
\{\text{homogeneous primes of $S$ not containing $x_i$}\} &\leftrightarrow \{\text{homogeneous primes of $S_{x_i}$}\} \\
& \leftrightarrow \{\text{prime ideals of $(S_{x_i})_0$}\}
\end{align*}
Note that $S_{x_i}$ is a $\mathbf{Z}$-graded ring and that $(S_{x_i})_0$ is often denoted $S_{(x_i)}$. There is a general fact for more general graded rings and elements (in place of $x_i$), but it's easier to prove when the element has degree $1$. If you get stuck on this, look at [this lemma](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00JO) in the Stacks Project.